# How to put a UIimage over a UIImage and choosing which one should be on top?

Tags: ios

Simple question I want to put a UIImage over another UIImage like so: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-circular-image-calayer/

And I've created the example project then applied it to my own project. But for some reason it put's the UIIprofile image below the background image.

Any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: You should post your code so we can help you. Even if we bothered to read the tutorial we can't assume you followed it correctly.

Comment: Are you adding them as subviews or is it organized in storyboard? If they're added as subviews make sure the images are added in order of furthest back to top. Same for storyboard but just dragging them around in order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bring a certain view to the back, you can use this method:

```
    [parentView sendSubviewToBack:view]
```

Alternitively, if you want to bring a certain view to the front, you can use this method:

```
    [parentView bringSubviewToFront:view]
```

If you use Storyboard, their order of appearance is dependant on their position in the view list.
[image]

Here Button will be behind the Scroll View in appearance.

Comment: Thanks it's solved. I had to re-order everything in my storyboard.